# UIAlertView Buttons(subviews) is not Showing in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview, ios7

UIAlertView is working fine in ios 6 with below code .But when it comes to ios 7 the subviews ( "yes" and "no" buttons in my code ) is not showing when alertview is called  only text message is showing .Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem ?

viewController.m file

```
 [Utilities prCustomAlert:@"Textmessage" inTitle:@"Alert view title" delegate:self inTag:300];
 CustomAlertView *alertView    = [Utilities sharedUtility].customAlertView;
alertView.numberOfBtns  = 2;
UIButton *btn= (UIButton *)[alertView viewWithTag:10];
[btn setTitle:@"no" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(dontlogout) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

btn = (UIButton *)[alertView viewWithTag:11];
[btn setTitle:@"yes" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(logout) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];    
[Utilities displayCustomAlertForDelegate:self];
```

UIAlertView.m file

```
  CGRect viewFrame    = self.frame;
  CGRect buttonFrame  = button.frame;
  if(self.numberOfBtns==2){

  CGRect labelFrame   = [self viewWithTag:15].frame;        
  button.frame    = CGRectMake(10, 0, 40, 30);
        button.hidden   = NO;

        //yes...
        btn          = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:11];       
        btn.frame    = CGRectMake(60, 0, 40, 30);
        btn.hidden   = NO;

        //no..    
        btn          = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:10];
        btn.hidden   = YES;


  }
```

Comment: The view hierarchy of `UIAlertView` has been private for a very long time. Apple started to enforce this in iOS7. Instead of manipulating the view hierarchy you have to create a UIView subclass that mimics UIAlertView.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Can you answer it in coding ? like how to create and add UIViews to UIAlertView

Comment: You can't add views to UIAlertView. You subclass UIView and make it look like UIAlertView. Check [cocoapods](http://www.cocoapods.org/?q=on%3Aios%20summary%3Aalert) for classes that do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add subviews to UIAlerView by adding subview to the presentedViewController's view when UIAlertView is presented. I have accessed UIAlertView like following way :

NSArray *subviews = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController.view.subviews;

I have created a subclass of UIAlerView :

Header File :

```
@interface MLKLoadingAlertView : UIAlertView

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;

@end
```

Implementation File :

```
#import "MLKLoadingAlertView.h"

#define ACTIVITY_INDICATOR_CENTER   CGPointMake(130, 90)

@implementation MLKLoadingAlertView

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    if ( self = [super init] )
    {
        self.title = title;
        self.message = @"\n\n";

        [self setDelegate:self];
    }

    return self;
}

// You can Customise this based on your requirement by adding subviews.
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    NSArray *subviews = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController.view.subviews;

    if( subviews.count > 1 )
    {
        // iOS while presenting an alertview uses a presening view controller. That controller's view has several subviews. I have picked one
        // subview from it which has frame similar to the alertview frame.
        UIView *presentedView = [subviews objectAtIndex:1];

         UIActivityIndicatorView *customActivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        [customActivityIndicator startAnimating];
        customActivityIndicator.center = ACTIVITY_INDICATOR_CENTER;

        [presentedView addSubview:customActivityIndicator];
    }
}

@end
```

In - (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView method I have added the subviews to UIAlertView by accessing Presented View Controller's view.

You can find explanation and code example for this on [Here](http://mlk-ios-programming-concepts.blogspot.in/2014/01/customisingadding-subviews-uialertview.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think the root of the problem in iOS7 that Apple changed the *UIAlertView* appearance mechanism.
From now any show of alertView follows after initiating of two private view controllers

```
_UIModalItemAppViewController
_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController
```

In other words, now UIAlertView is not a pure view - it is a part of some complicated collection of view controllers with full view controller life cycle.

But a good news that you can change *accessoryView* to your *customContentView* in a standard alert view

```
[alertView setValue:customContentView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

Note that you must call this before *[alertView show]*.

Answer (score 1):

What you were doing was always wrong. You are not allowed to add your own subviews to a UIAlertView. The good news is - in iOS 7, you don't have to! The new custom transition animation mechanism lets you make your own view that behaves just an alert view, but since it is your view, you can put anything you like into it, like this:

[image]

Note how the fake "alert view" floats in front of the original view in the screen shot on the right, and dims the screen behind it, just like a real alert view. But it is made up entirely of custom content; a "real" alert view could never contain an image and a switch!

For the code that creates this view, which you can easily adapt to your own purposes, see my github site: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7