# iOS7 UIAlertView style dialog for custom views

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uialertview

I need to create a view that allows input of text. For my iOS 6 apps I have used alert views, which work perfectly, and when run from Xcode 5 show up as iOS 7 style white dialogs, with blurred backgrounds.

The problem is that I think that I cannot create an alert with multiple text fields on an iOS 7 dialog. I need three input fields.

Is there a standard setting for a UIView that creates this iOS 7 style dialog, but also works with iOS 6 devices? For instance UIAlertViews, UIActionSheets, and pickers all automatically style for iOS 6 or 7 depending on the device they are run on. Isn't there a standard view, similar to an alert view, that you can add text fields to etc to create a similar performance?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you want to have a View in which you can put three editable textfields and it should appear as an alertview and should also also blur the background when appears. If this is the case, then you can see `RNBlurModalView` class [here](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNBlurModalView) in the github.

Comment: Thanks, that is great, but UIAlertViews, UIActionSheets, and pickers all automatically style for iOS 6 or 7 depending on the device they are run on. Isn't there a standard view, similar to an alert view, that you can add text fields to etc to create a similar performance?

Comment: You cannot have three textfields in alertview because Apple discourages it. You can present a view modally though using UIPresentationFormSheet but that would cover half of a view and used in iPads only. So, RNBlurModalView is yopur best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at UIAlertViewStyle which is shown clearly on this blog post:http://mlk-ios-programming-concepts.blogspot.com/2013/08/uialertviewstyle-property-of-uialertview.html

Comment: Will do, thanks. We have to see if it works in iOS7.

Comment: If you want to customise UIAlerView in iOS 7, refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964046/uialertview-buttonssubviews-is-not-showing-in-ios-7/21307717#21307717